# Pygame, player beating high score causes game to not display death screen

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to copy from the app store in pygame for practice, i have set up a system where if you beat the current high score it will write it into the file so that it can be saved for later so the user can try and beat their score.

```
def player_death(player_score):  # What happens when the player dies
    end_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 50)
    print("You have died")  # For debugging

    score_file = open('data/score.txt', 'a')  # Don't think this is related
    score_file.write(str(player_score))       # Don't think this is related
    score_file.close()                        # Don't think this is related 

    b_score_file = open('data/score_best.txt', 'r')
    score_read = int(b_score_file.read())
    b_score_file.close()

    if player_score >= score_read:
        b_score_file = open('data/score_best.txt', 'w')
        b_score_file.write(str(player_score))
        b_score_file.close()

        print("New best score!")  # For debugging
        print(score_read)  # For debugging
        return best_score2
```

Every time the player collides with a Rect it adds to the score, in the main game loop that is then passed as 'player_score' to be used in the death screen, there is a loop and other stuff in the function, but i think i have narrowed it down to this part. If more code is need i can add. The thing is it works completely fine if the high score saved in the score_best.txt is higher than the score you just got. In the main loop of code i have it so if you collide with the rect either at the top or the bottom of the screen it will run the function above. If any more information is needed, feel free to ask, as i am running out of ideas.

When the player hits either of the parts that run this function it still detects it and runs the "you have died" print statement but then the actual screen which has been drawn through this function (not shown in the pasted code) doesn't show and just makes the player hit the ground and bounce off.

Comment: `return best_score2` where is this variable defined? Doesn't this crash your game?

Comment: No it didn't cause crashes, i meant to  rename that, i then did  rename it, it didn't fix it... then i just removed that line altogether and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the line

```
return best_score2
```

This fixed the issues.